# Are there popular pc or xbox one games that support a API?

Tags: api

I am looking for a API from a popular game. 
Googled a lot and seems to be very hard to find information or api's from games.

A lot for mobile apps but not looking for that.

Comment: Look at the popular MMOs, most of them have API. [Guild Wars 2](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:Main), [World of Warcraft](https://dev.battle.net/)... That said, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this, but I believe Blizzard has a [pretty extensive API](https://dev.battle.net/) which I believe is free. They have many popular games played by millions of people, including World of Warcraft, Starcraft, Overwatch, etc.